# Unable to debug Azure cloud service project

Tags: c#, azure, iis, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I'm using visual studio 2017, SQL Server 2017 developer edition and Azure Cloud Service project on Windows 10. I'm trying to debug an existing Azure Cloud Service application in my local environment but it doesn't work.

It throws below error each time emulator starts and then does nothing.

[image]

I've already set up admin and front site in IIS with IIS binding (https and http) and respective application pools.

After googling I found that, I need to enable 32-bit application setting in application pool but no avail. I also added startup task in ServiceDefinition.csdef file as shown below for each web role.

```
<Startup>
      <Task commandLine="enable32bit.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background"/>
    </Startup>
```

**enable32bit.cmd**

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools 
-applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
EXIT /B 0
```

After doing all these changes, I'm still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

The output for the role in the Compute Emulator displays the following log indefinitely:

> [fabric] Role Instance:
>   [fabric] Role state Busy
>  
>   [fabric] Role state Aborted 
>  
>   [fabric] Role state Busy 
>  
>   [fabric] Role state Aborted 
>  
>   [fabric] Role state Busy 
>  
>   [fabric] Role state Aborted 
>  
>   [fabric] Role state Busy

Comment: Please check if the service role instance are running in Compute Emulator. Does it return error every time when you press F5 to launch debugging sessions?

Comment: Please see the edit.